# django-social-auth registration extra step

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm  using django-social-auth & custom User model (django 1.5) with extra fields which are required. I need the user to fill these fields before the models is saved. Is there any way to "interrupt" the django-social-auth right after the backend authorization succeeded, but before the new User model is created, in order to show the form asking for account details?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You add a [pipeline entry](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html) which returns a `HttpResponseRedirect` to any place you need. Check the example app with django-social-auth, it cuts the pipeline in two places ([here](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/example/settings.py#L166) and [here](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/example/settings.py#L173)) to ask the user some extra information. The first one takes place before the user instance is created.

Check the `save_status_to_session` call before each break, that is required to ensure the pipeline status when it's continued.

Comment: great, thank you. While browsing the docs, I've ommited reading the pipeline section when stumbled upon the sentence saying "Each pipeline entry must return a dict or None, any value in the dict will be used in the kwargs argument for the next pipeline entry.". Please consider changing it as it's misleading ... ;)

Comment: @omab thanks for pointing out  __it cuts the pipeline in two places ([here](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/example/settings.py#L166) and [here](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/example/settings.py#L173))__